# Can not type à , ê , è anymore

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

Problem: Can not write accents like à, ê .

Here is my configuration:

- Windows 7
- Keyboard configuration : French Canadian

Description:
Recently (2 days before), I could type these letters à, ê, è, I used to press the accent key and the letter I want to be accentuated. That means if I want to write ê I press the key "^" before and then the key "e". It was working fine now it is not.

I didn't make any change to the system, I suspect windows updates.

Note: I have this problem only with some software: Outlook, Notepad++ wich I use all the time.

Comment: have you tried alt+shift?

Comment: This functionality is not built into windows 7, but some applications support it, like Word. I've never seen this in Notepad++, and wouldn't expect it, because I'd expect the ^ character to appear, not wait for another character to accent.

Comment: Check that your keyboard layout is recognized correctly and make sure you have French installed in your language settings. Is this a French or English windows? Qwerty or azerty keyboard?

Comment: i have the same problem - solved only by restart. it is not a keyboard layout problem. the keys with accent just stop working. if i switch layout the key works - with the character for this layout.

Answer (score 3):

What could have happened is that you pressed the keystroke to change the keyboard layout (most likely not on purpose). That keystroke is **CTRL + SHIFT**. Pressing it again will basically tell windows to switch to the next "keyboard layout" in the list of your computer.

When you install Windows vista, 7 or 8 with french canada, Windows by default will also install the layout for US qwerty based keyboards. So when you press that combination, Windows is switching to the US layout, hence why you lose your accents.

A quick fix to this problem is to press **CTRL + SHIFT** again to gain access to the other keyboard layout, which is most likely french canada in your case.

You could also fix the issue by deleting any keyboard layout aside of french canada (assuming you use nothing else). By doing so, even if you press that combination accidentally, it won't switch to anything else because the only thing that it sees is french canada.

Comment: I have access to the french keyboard, i can type the letter "é" for example without problems. this one takes only one key, but for accents like "è" it take two keys that you must press one after the other.
It's working on some software and parts of the system like the execute window, the address bar of a windows but not working on  others like : Outlouk, Office, textarea in a HTML page, etc .
I will try again the shorcuts you proposed and give you a feed-back (i dont have acess to the other computer now ...) .

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT does not resolve the problem. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: I needed to re-install my preferred language (in Windows 10, but I don't think it's much different in Windows 7).

In my case, I had ENG and NLD (Dutch). I couldn't use accents anymore either. 
`á` became `'a`, etc. 
My solution that worked was as follows: press the Windows button and search for "settings" and open them. Search for "language" and click it ("Language Settings", "Region and Language", or whatever looks most promising). Then, click your language (in your case French-Canadian) and click "remove". Then click "Add a preferred language" and find your language again and install it. In my case it worked again after these steps.

Also, during this process I noticed that
pressing <kbd>Windows button</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd> changed from ENG to NLD (which used to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, I believe). 
Could be a Windows 10 thing, not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurred for me only after I installed French as the computer language. I deleted French as the computer language, and I could once again use accents, etc. The problem, if it is the same, is in some way associated with the computer language, it seems. However, on my other computer, I have three computer languages installed, French being one of them, and yet the problem does not occur...

Answer (score 0):

Deleting and re installing the languague, Spanish in my case, did not solved the problem.  Somehow it seems to occur with internet based programs and not with harddrive installed programs.  Only way to put accents in vowels now is to enter the Ascii Code.  Ie. ALT 160 for á.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the language, but the keyboard associated with the language:

- Go to languages settings
- Click on the language (*English (United States)* for me)
- Click on *Add a keyboard*
- Select *United States-International*
- You can then remove the previous keyboard