# Shift accented letters not working on Windows 10

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout

So accented letters using Shift just stopped working here. This never happened to me before. I'm wondering VERY much what the heck happened, because I see it's all in Portuguese language on the computer, and still, weird letters I never saw appear around haha.

I can write Ê, but not in lower case. This appears instead: Ņ (when I tried to type it here, instead an "e" appeared, not that weird N). Another example is the grave accent. I can write À, but not in lower case. Instead, nothing appears (wow, just found out --> ????????). Again, here appears just an "a".

On the bottom it's the Portuguese keyboard layout if it's of any help.

I've no idea why this is happening. I never saw this happen in my life, so exactly no idea what's happening, nor I know what to ask Google about it (asked some ideas but nothing appeared - didn't make an exaustive search though, as I hope someone here may know the answer and spare me the time I should be studying and would be searching everything to find an answer).

Main notes:

- This is only happening with lower case letters;
- This is only happening with accents. I can type ) or ? or * or whatever, like all the capital letter I typed here so far. So it may mean that the system is using any other layout (that weird N seems to be on Latvian language) when I press Shift and an accent. It waits, and when I type a letter, it replaces both of the things it memorized with a wrong letter (or none in case of lower case À).

Does anyone know what this is...? Hope it's not Windows 10's problem (never saw this on any other system). I need to write it haha --> WTF!?!?!?!?!? xD

**PS:** I'm using Build 1809, but that's only as a reference. Any ideas for any build versions are welcomed.

Thanks in advance for any help! Would be interesting to write Portuguese again hahaha. Hopefully someone knows the answer to this and I don't need to reinstall Windows or something like that. If this is another shortcut..... I just found out why sometimes the keyboard would change from PT to EN "by itself" --> Left Alt+Shift. I never knew of that shortcut until 10 minutes ago... This has happened for some years and I never looked on Google. Now I just found out...

**UPDATE:** Not only what I said.... I can't write upper case õ using Shift... I'd do Tilde, Shift+O and that would write an upper case õ. Now nothing happens.

Also, e with a tilde is not supposed to exist in Portuguese. Doing Tilde+E (lower case), appears ~e, which is correct. If I do Tilde, Shift+E, the weird N appears again. Nothing was supposed to appear!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fast. Sorry for asking, I guess.

I kept searching a bit more and I found this question here on SuperUser: [Can not type à , ê , è anymore](https://superuser.com/questions/573322/can-not-type-%C3%A0-%C3%AA-%C3%A8-anymore). A person there says they had to reinstall the language. So I thought in going on Language inside Time and Language settings and changing the language to English (default system language) and back to Portuguese. Then I saw another language was appearing bellow Portuguese, which was English. Wasn't supposed, as I don't want to switch between the 2, so I removed it (didn't uninstall though, just clicked Remove - it appears again if I select English as the system language). When I tried to write again, the letters were working --> ê, à, ~E, Õ. All as it was supposed.

I swear I didn't understand what happened here. I had also tried Ctrl+Shift to change layouts, but nothing was happening (and I disabled the 2 shortcuts - switch language and switch layout, and I'm gonna put a note to disable them on all my computers, so nothing like this or changing from PT to EN ever happens again from nothing).

Though, if anyone else has other solutions, no problems in putting bellow, even though I'll accept this answer in 2 days if I still remember haha.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I use English as the display language for windows and apps but use a Portuguese(Portugal) layout keyboard.

I solved it by installing UK English to replace US English, keeping Portuguese-PT for the keyboard layout.